Trouble making Cyclone DDS working
I'm trying to use the Cyclone DDS for an application of mine but it seems that it is not working in my case. I tried and followed all the steps as described in https://cyclonedds.io/docs/cyclonedds/latest/installation/installation.html. The building and installation was done without any issue. I also created a configuration.xml file as below (actually it is the same xml as described in https://cyclonedds.io/docs/cyclonedds/latest/config/index.html without the Tracing tag):
xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?CycloneDDS xmlns="https://cdds.io/config" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://cdds.io/config https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eclipse-cyclonedds/cyclonedds/master/etc/cyclonedds.xsd"
Domain Id="any" General Interfaces NetworkInterface autodetermine="true" priority="default" multicast="default" /Interfaces AllowMulticast default /AllowMulticast MaxMessageSize 65500B /MaxMessageSize /General /Domain /CycloneDDS
and exported the CYCLONEDDS_URI as per instructions:
env | grep CYCLONEDDS_URI
CYCLONEDDS_URI=file:///home/giannis/install_location/configuration.xml
However, when I try to run the executables HelloworldPublisher and HelloworldSubscriber, it seems that there are no packages transferred (I opened two terminals in the same machine and ran each of the executables as described in the https://cyclonedds.io/docs/cyclonedds/latest/installation/installation.html under the "Test your installation" section:
./HelloworldPublisher
=== [Publisher]  Waiting for a reader to be discovered ...
./HelloworldSubscriber
=== [Subscriber] Waiting for a sample ...
Am I missing something here? Can someone please help me?
Thanks
